# learning sites for fixing java memory leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks, visualvm, jhat

What would be the best places to learn fixing a java memory leak ? I have been trying to find good resource over the NET but to my disappointment, I find toy examples being discussed. I am also able to troubleshoot small toy dumps but the real world application dumps are more challenging and give little clue.

I have tried tools like Jhat, JMap, VisualVM and MAT.

what would be the best place to learn about fixing Java memory leaks ? suggestion of a book is also welcome.

thanks in advance.

Comment: am yet to try JProf. Tomorrow is the day :-)

Comment: but there's no magic tool to do stuff for you... they're all good for particular use-cases. if it was possible, i'd suggest valgrind. it'll boil down to you knowing how to use the tool and understand the output :)

Comment: i would highly recommend using yourkit java profiler.  it's not free, but it's well worth the money.

Comment: if you're opening your wallet, you might even shell out some bucks for Chronon and keep replaying the leak scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried searching the [internet](http://java.dzone.com/news/how-fix-memory-leaks-java)?  There are many [examples](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-leaks/).  A good search engine will sort them by [relevance](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-leaks/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there was a touch of arrogance in it :-). I did walk through a lot of sites ( including this one ). My problem is that real world apps are very different than these toy applications that are mostly discussed. A real world dump is full off char[] and String objects, how to sort and proceed with thousands of such objects. most of them seem valid :-( Yes, I am new to java dumps.

Comment: @Geek - you're right, sorry.  I had too much coffee today.  Can you paste your example dump and see if we can help more?

Comment: @Geek, I suggest you use an evaluation version of a professional profiler. I use YourKit and this is good for sorting through lots of data and find the "hot spots".

Comment: @AmirAfghani & Peter : Thanks for the answer. I have a question : Most of my dump is just filled with Strings and char[]. Interestingly there are big duplicate Strings but when I do a paths to GC in VisualVM, I generally get "No Roots found". Can you please throw light on this.

Answer (score 2):

There are many kind of memory leaks but in practice the following strategy gives good results (Disclaimer: I'm showing screen shots from [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), because my company develops it):

**1. Check the biggest objects**

"Biggest objects" retain a lot of memory that nobody else is holding on to. In JProfiler, they can be found in the "Biggest objects" view of the heap walker. This often happens with caches.

[image]

**2. Check classes with a lot of instances**

Sometimes, the references are more intricate and the biggest objects do not give a clue. Classes with a lot of instances can be checked for their incoming references. First, it is helpful to look at cumulated references, to separate valid reference chains from suspicious reference chains.

[image]

Also, checking where instances have been allocated (as opposed to how they are referenced) can often give an insight on what is going on.

[image]

Often, this is a multi-step process, selecting reference chains, allocation spots, or making selections based on the contents of objects.

**3. Search for paths to GC roots**

If that still does not provide a clue, you can select single objects and show their reference chains that lead to garbage collector roots. It helps a lot of you were able to narrow down an object set of suspicious objects before trying to to that, otherwise you may have a lot of candidates.

[image]

There is also a [screen cast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/04/in-screencast-below-i-show-strategy-for.html) on this topic.

Comment: @Kegel : Most of my dump is just filled with Strings and char[]. Interestingly there are big duplicate Strings but when I do a paths to GC in VisualVM, I generally get "No Roots found" :-( To my understanding that these objects should be garbage collected but are existing for more than 1 day in the heap ?

Comment: @Geek It is possible to have non-referenced objects on the heap for a long time, it depends on what generation they are in when they were unreferenced. Another possibility is that the strings are soft-referenced or weak-referenced, so there is no path to a GC root. JProfiler (by default) removes weakly referenced objects when analyzing a heap snapshot, because they usually makes things harder to analyze.

Comment: It is quite common to see Strings and theirs inner char[] on the top of the heap in any Java application. You can try your luck with the objects that come after them in the Biggest objects list