# Memory Leak in JSPs

Tags: jsp, memory-management, memory-leaks, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am trying to work on a memory leak issue. I was analyzing a heap dump and I found that some of the JSPs are using around 51 mb of heap space. Could you please let me know what could be the possible reason. Please find below screenshot of the dump.[image]

Comment: Your code would be much more useful than a screenshot.

Comment: I wont be able to share code as it is in secured environment. I just want to understand what elements of jsp can lead to such memory leaks.

Comment: Well, _what elements of jsp can lead to such memory leaks_ - usually badly written code. So without posting code, you have either to google `java memory leak`, or hire an expert. Anyway, two links that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736759/3511123 and https://www.toptal.com/java/hunting-memory-leaks-in-java

Comment: Thanks @JozefChocholacek...I was able to find the source for this leak. As screenshot shows, NodeCustomTag objects were created in heap. So I looked into the custom tag library that was used. The library had that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your contribution.

I was able to find the solution for this memory leak. The leak was due to incorrectly written custom tag library. I referred the below mentioned link.

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2009/08/jsp-tag-pooling-memory-leaks-2/